# Google Charts with data from MongoDB in Python

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, charts

I'm trying to set data from database MongoDB for drawing Google Chart in python.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
from string import Template
import pprint


cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://saman:1234@cluster0-vhwfp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db= cluster["Test"]
collection= db["Test"]


rm=list(collection.find({}))

chart_data_str= ''
results= collection.find({})
for x in results:
    chart_data_str += '%s,\n' %x
    
print(chart_data_str)
```

I want to know, How can I change the folowing format

```
{'_id': 5, 'name': 'Mahdi', 'Score': 9},
{'_id': 1, 'name': 'Ali', 'Score': 3},
{'_id': 3, 'name': 'Christian', 'Score': 6},
{'_id': 4, 'name': 'Niklas', 'Score': 1},
{'_id': 2, 'name': 'Dominik', 'Score': 2},
{'_id': 0, 'name': 'Saman', 'Score': 5},
```

to thises format

```
['Mahdi', 9],
['Ali', 3],
['Christian', 6],
['Niklas', 1],
['Dominik', 2],
['Saman', 5]
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print that out as a string:

```
for result in collection.find({}, {'_id': 0}):
    print(f"[{result.get('name')}, {result.get('Score')}],")
```

If this isn't what you want, please clarify your question.